# How to split a text with several headings and subsequent text into two columns using postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql, fasta

My test looks as follows: I have several text pieces with a one-line header introduced by a '>'. It is not clear which kind of text appears in the header, only that it is just one line. 
The length of the text piece after the header can vary. Also there might be empty lines inbetween as shown between text parts one and two (see below). Also the number of text pieces is variable.

```
>Sequenz 1 Test 1234
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGEVAAQL

>Sequenz 2 | Test: 1234
SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGEVAAQL
>Sequenz 3 : Test : 1234
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGEVAAQL
```

I want to split it into two columns. One with the header without the leading '>'. The second column should contain the corresponding text part.

```
|Header                          |Text
|--------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------
|Sequenz 1 Test 1234             |MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
|                                |LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
|                                |IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
|                                |MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGEVAAQL
|--------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------   
|Sequenz 2 | Test: 1234         |SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
|                                |ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
|                                |LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
|                                |IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
|                                |MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGEVAAQL
|--------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------
|Sequenz 3 : Test : 1234       |MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
|                                |LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
|                                |IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
|                                |MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGEVAAQL
|--------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I have already a select statement to extract the header.

```
SELECT split_part(regexp_split_to_table(trim(leading '>' 
FROM 'text from above'), E'>'),E'\n', 1)
```

But I have really no clue how the split the text after the header into the second column. I appreciate the help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will capture the header in group one and the text in group two.

```
>(.*)([\s\S]*?)(?=\R>|$)
```

It captures everything after the `>` up to a linefeed. Then it captures everything up to a linefeed followed by a `>`, **or** end of string.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TihR2H/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. What I can see from the regex101 it looks really promising. Since I would like to achieve two separate database columns I wonder how I can detangle this regex  to use it for two statements.